# unable to install latest version of rlang rstudio

Tags: r, rlang, install.packages

Im trying to install the latest (or at least version 0.4.3 required for another package) of rlang but can only install v 3.5.

I have tried to close down Rstudio/restart session, remove and re-install using:

```
install.packages("rlang")
install.packages("rlang", type="source")
devtools::install_github("rlang")
remotes::install_github("r-lib/rlang")
install.packages("rlang_0.4.9.tar.gz", repo=NULL, type="source")
```

the error messages i get is

> Error: Failed to install 'rlang' from GitHub:
> (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpARJArh
> /file46b06f822b7a/rlang_0.4.10.9000.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

I have also tried to remove dplyr (the package i want to use that depends on rlang v.0.4.3) and reinstalling but it still gives me the error message:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in
> loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()),           versionCheck =
> vI[[i]]): namespace ‘rlang’ 0.3.4 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.3 is
> required

There seems to be a common problem with installing rlang, bu havnt been able to find a solution on any forum except those that I have tried.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What version of R do you have installed?

Comment: Newest version of Rstudio 3.5.3

Comment: Hi, When you say you have Rstudio 3.53, I think you are confusing R for Rstudio. The latest version of RStudio Desktop is 1.4.1103. But the latest version of R is 4.0.3. It sounds like you are running R 3.5.3, which was released in March 2019, and you are trying to do something that requires a more recent version of R and rlang.  So, my suggestion is to update R to the newest version from [cran](https://cran.r-project.org/). And then to update all your packages.  This might fix your issue.

Comment: Worked! I had the old r and newest desktop. I downloaded the newest version and it worked. Thanks for bearing with me!

Comment: Great, glad it's been fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I removed the library from the file system and installed it from scratch and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I've removed the rlang package and installed the devtools one. The rlang has been installed with it.